# gke nginx lb health checks / can't get all instances in a "healthy" state

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Using nginx `nginx-ingress-controller:0.9.0`, below is the permanent state of the google cloud load balancer :

[image]

Basically, the single healthy node is the one running the nginx-ingress-controller pods. Besides not looking good on this screen, everything works super fine. Thing is, Im' wondering why such bad notice appears on the lb

Here's [the service/deployment](https://gist.github.com/benbonnet/14f0c3efc7a2edd7b50351e825e39353) used

Am just getting a little lost over how thing works; hope to get some experienced feedback on how to do thing right (I mean, getting green lights on all nodes), or to double check if that's a drawback of not using the 'official' gcloud l7 thing

Comment: Can you include the manifest for your nginx ingress controller and the corresponding service?

Comment: thx; added the link above. basically its the one provided https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/deploy/provider, am just not using a different namespace, and setting the static ip on the service rather than on the ingress

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Service` is using the `service.beta.kubernetes.io/external-traffic: OnlyLocal` annotation. This configures it so that traffic arriving at the NodePort for that service will never go a `Pod` on another node. Since your `Deployment` only has 1 replica, the only node that will receive traffic is the one where the 1 Pod is running.

If you scale your `Deployment` to 2 replicas, 2 nodes will be healthy, etc.

Using that annotation is a recommend configuration so that you are not introducing additional network hops.

Comment: ok I got the expected result. But I'm still confused as I can't see how things go through; nginx is just proxying to a another service, so do you mean this part will only occur on specific node ? I don't get how things are tied to a specific node as anywhere a deployment/pod is, it'll be reached — and in case a deployment/pod has a single replica, it won't necessarly be on the node where the traffic has been received first

Comment: Nginx is getting the traffic first, but then it can forward the traffic to any node in any pod according to `Ingress` configurations.